# how to change url of "add to wishlist" button in magento

Tags: magento

I am designing a magento website and I am new to it. I am unable to find where to change the URL of Add to Wishlist button.
I have attached the screenshot to check if someone needs.

I will be obliged if someone provides a solution.
[addtowishlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjCJ6.png)

Comment: what exactly you want to do? can you explain more clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the URL from the following template file:

```
template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml
```

Comment: <?php if ($b['product']['addlinks_wishlist'] && $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-dark btn-outline" role="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_wishlistSubmitUrl ?>')"><?php echo $this->__(' Add to Wishlist') ?></button>

Comment: Now I am not able to know how to change this $_WishlistSubmitUrl. How to change this url?

Comment: what exactly you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
your_theme > default > template > catalog  > product > view > addto.phtml


<?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
<a href="<?php echo $_wishlistSubmitUrl ?>" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submitLight(this, this.href); return false;" class="link-wishlist">
    <?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>
</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here you can change `href`.